# Regex only matching one case where repeating matches are present?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, data-cleaning

## [PYTHON 3.7]

- Using `re` Module

This is my `re.search` string:

```
'(?<=Access {)[\w\W]+(?=~Access)'
```

I have also tried:

```
'Access[\w\W]+Access'
```

*My test string:*

```
4 : {'IsMissing': 'false', 'Name': 'Trans7', 'Number': '7', 'ProgrammingLanguage': 'LAD'}~FlgNet {}~Parts {}~Access {'Scope': 'LocalVariable', 'UId': '21'}~Symbol {}~Component {'Name': 'DATA'}~Component {'Name': 'sOFF'}~Access {'Scope': 'LocalVariable', 'UId': '22'}~Symbol {}~Component {'Name': 'Me'}~Component {'Name': 'SEQ03'}~Component {'Name': 'sRUN'}~Part {'Name': 'Contact', 'UId': '23'}~Part {'Name': 'Contact', 'UId': '24'}~Negated {'Name': 'operand'}~Part {'Name': 'TrCoil', 'UId': '25'}~Wires {}~Wire {'UId': '26'}~Powerrail {}~NameCon {'UId': '23', 'Name': 'in'}~Wire {'UId': '27'}~IdentCon {'UId': '21'}~NameCon {'UId': '23', 'Name': 'operand'}~Wire {'UId': '28'}~NameCon {'UId': '23', 'Name': 'out'}~NameCon {'UId': '24', 'Name': 'in'}~Wire {'UId': '29'}~IdentCon {'UId': '22'}~NameCon {'UId': '24', 'Name': 'operand'}~Wire {'UId': '30'}~NameCon {'UId': '24', 'Name': 'out'}~NameCon {'UId': '25', 'Name': 'in'}~
```

I only get **`1`** match:

```
Access {'Scope': 'LocalVariable', 'UId': '21'}~Symbol {}~Component {'Name': 'DATA'}~Component {'Name': 'sOFF'}~Access
```

Which I have tested in [Pythex](https://pythex.org/).

I have been using [re Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) as a reference to do the Regex.

Any advice or 'better practice' for a solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect more than 1 match? There's only one pair of `Access {` and `~Access`

Comment: If your real string has multiple matches, use `+?` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: @Barmar so if I want to return all strings in a new list that occur between `Access {` and `~Access` - how can I got about it?

Comment: in your case there is only one string. The one you caught/matched

Comment: Like I said, use `+?` to match the quantifier non-greedy. Then use `re.findall()` to get a list of matches.

Comment: And instead of `[\w\W]`, use `.` and use the `re.DOTALL` flag to make it match anything, including newline.

Comment: Ohh yes - Thank you @Barmar

Comment: When you give an example you should always show your desired result.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Noted, I'll remember that one thanks.